# Getting more than 3200 tweets and their replies

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I want to retrieve more than 3200 tweets belongs to a specific user. I also need the replies too. As far as I know, twitter API limits it (with 3200), but is there any work around to get more, possibly all tweets belong to a specific user. Any language, tools, code are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to get around Twitter's limit?

Comment: What the heck is all this down votes? I am so struggling to find a proper way. Instead of damned downvoting, you should give an answer?

Comment: I need further analysis @PeterWood, do you have any idea?

Comment: "How do I abuse the limits of someone else's service" questions tend to get a poor reception, because you're trying to abuse the limits of someone else's service.

Comment: This is a legitimate question. I don't see where it asks for ways to abuse or get around the rate limits.

Comment: @Jonas: From the question: "As far as I know, twitter API limits it (with 3200), but is there any work around to get more"

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-get-Twitter-paid-API-details

Comment: @user2357112 Twitter does provide a way to access these older tweets. You just have to pay for the access. That is the work-around. You assumed the questioner meant "abuse."

Comment: Even I wanted a way to get more than 3200 tweets and I thought scraping the public Twitter profile page would be the solution. So, I ended up scraping a maximum of 3400 tweets using HTMLUnit (Java). The idea was to access the non-JavaScript Twitter page and _simulate_ hitting "Load more Tweets" button at the end of the page to load as many tweets as possible. So, eventually, this "Load more Tweets" button disappears and you will have 3400 tweets on average. So, the only way to access more than, say, 4000 tweets of a person, you need to buy the Enterprise version of Twitter API.

Comment: This tool may help: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/twitter-dump

Answer (score 2):

As you mention in your question, the Twitter API does not support getting more than 3200 tweets from a user's timeline. However, there is a way to get these tweets that does not violate Twitter's usage policy. Twitter instead licenses access to these tweets. For example, you can pay to use [Gnip's](https://gnip.com/) API's for accessing the tweets you are looking for.